# Google Places API - closed POIs?

Tags: google-places-api

Google Maps seems to have information about whether a place is closed (permanently closed) or opened, but it seems like this information is not available in Google Places API.
Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 5):

`permanently_closed` *is a boolean flag indicating whether the place has permanently shut down (value true). If the place is not permanently closed, the flag is absent from the response.*
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults (2015+)

Also, Places Autocomplete API will prefer places that are not permanently closed, although you might still get one if there's no better match for user input.

Answer (score -1):

Google Places API have information that place is open or close at the current time but not  permanently closed or opened.

For more information check this documentation
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults